# How to identify number of nodes and layers in lstm model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have time-series classification problem where I use a dataset of 2000 data point. Each data point has 4 timeseries that are 25 length long.

I am using the following LSTM model on this dataset.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(25,4)))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The above model gave me really bad results (nearly 0.3). This is really upsetting and now I am looking for ways to improve my results.

I think the problem is with the number of nodes I use in each layer (i.e. `10` and `32` respectively). My question is, is there a way to identify how many nodes we need in each layer? Moreover, is it sufficient to have one `LSTM` layer and one `Dense` layer? Do you think that I can improve these layers?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: This is totally dependent on your data and whether you are interpreting/loading it correctly. There isn't an answer.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you for the comment. Since I am new to deep learning, I just want to clarify, if it is correct to increase the number of nodes in the two layers. Say 1000 nodes and 500 for the first and second layer? I look forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: It's possible, but I'd try less at first. You can also try more layers. But if your data is quite randomic, it won't learn. If your data is not in the range of sigmoid, it won't learn. If you didn't interpret what are "steps" and "features" correctly, it won't learn.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions above, you might want to consider running for more epochs and see if the loss continues to decrease which is indicating that the network is "learning" so you might be on the right track.  Sometimes LSTMs take quite a while to perform well.  You also might want to consider metrics other than "accuracy" to make sure you are actually measuring the performance you care about.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you for your comment. Do you mean adding more dense layers such as `model.add(Dense(32))`. Please kindly correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: I think that applying the model to a test set (i.e. data not used in the training) would be a first step.  You can use the model.evaluate() function to generate the estimated loss and accuracy metric(s).  If this number is pretty comparable to your training accuracy (say close to 0.75) then your model may be generalizing well and not overfitting, but if it is quite low, then you might suspect overfitting.  I hope this helps.